# Heroku Paperclip S3 error => AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

Paperclip+S3 work on the local machine but dont work on Heroku. It says **"AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch"**

> 2012-04-20T21:24:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô",
>   "authenticit y_token"=>"MHt20N64y9L24Ga2y6gGj8hX06U+td17XIRdqMadcCQ=",
>   "post"=>{"title"=>"tes t", "organisation_id"=>"1", "content"=>"weeqw",
>   "attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>
>   {"pic"=>#>}}},
>   "commit"=>"Create Post"} 2012-04-20T21:24:41+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 344 6ms
>   2012-04-20T21:24:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-04-20T21:24:41+00:00
>   app[web.1]: **AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch** (Th e request
>   signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Che
>   ck your key and signing method.):

Here is my attachment.rb model:

```
   has_attached_file :pic, :styles => { :medium => "500x280>",:slide => "180x260>", :thumb => "150x100#" },     
:storage => :s3,
             :bucket => 'sample_bucket',
             :s3_credentials => {
               :access_key_id => 'ASDDSAMPLEKEYDFSDF',
               :secret_access_key => 'Dfsdf887-sample-secret-key-dfdsasd',
             }
```

What might be the reason of this error?

Answer (score 1):

I've paperclip 2.4.5 and here is the definition inside the model:

```
has_attached_file :logo,
                :path => "assets/:class/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
                :storage => :s3,
                :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
                :s3_permissions => 'authenticated-read',
                :s3_protocol => "http",
                :s3_credentials => { :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
                                     :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'] },
                :styles => { :index => "72x72>",
                             :billboard => "120x120>" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having some similar issues with Heroku and found this https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip-aws.

This solved my problem.